# Add control in image detail panel

Tags: customization, media-settings, media-modal

I am trying to add a checkbox control in the image details popup (when editing image in a post). I have added the following code in my template `function.php` but I can't manage to display the checkbox in the popup. What am I missing?

```
function bluesolutions_customize_register($wp_customize) {
  $wp_customize->add_section('bluesolutions_use_lighbox_section', array(
      'title' => __('Lightbox', 'mytheme'),
      'description' => '',
      'priority' => 120,
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_setting('mytheme_use_lighbox_setting', array(
      'default' => 0,
      'capability' => '',
      'type' => 'checkbox',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
          $wp_customize, 'use_lighbox', array(
      'label' => __('Usen lightbox', 'mytheme'),
      'section' => 'advanced',
      'settings' => 'mytheme_use_lighbox_setting',
      'priority' => 1,
      'type' => 'checkbox',
          )
  ));
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'bluesolutions_customize_register' );
```

[image]

Comment: The hook you are using (and related code) `customize_register` is meant for the theme customization page... not the editor "edit image" window.  I'm not sure which hook to use for the "Image Details" window.  Perhaps someone else can chime in here?

Comment: OK thanks, I will try to find te right hook to use.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm looking for the same answer.

Comment: I'm curious what the hook is for this as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
function your_slug_edit_media_custom_checkbox( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['custom_field'] = array(
        'label' => 'Custom Field',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_field', true )
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
function your_slug_save_media_custom_field( $post, $attachment ) {
    update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_custom_field', $attachment['custom_field'] );
    return $post;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'edit_media_custom_checkbox', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'save_media_custom_checkbox', 11, 2 );
```